# Next.js page dimensions are way bigger than viewport

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I stumbled upon the strange effect where my page dimensions are about 2.7 times bigger than the viewport, even with no content and no styles. It is as if the page was scaled up, but it isn't the case.

[image: Viewport is smaller]

This project is built on the base of NEXT.js template project but even if template doesn't have the same problem, I fail to see when or where it happened. There is no `webpack` settings on the project and no UI javascript added by me. There is no setting of `html` or `body` except for `100%`.
I have tried to reset `zoom` and `scale` on everything, but nothing happens. Even when I scroll with mousewheel, nothing happened, like there is some block. I feel like I missing something very basic, but googling brought no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I looked in the wrong place.
One of the contributors slipped in this meta tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover" />`, which was the culprit.